# Selecting the selected value in PHP for loop and HTML select options - not working?

Tags: php, html, loops

Here's the loop and code:

```
$rev_sel = 0.01;
    for($i=1.00; $i>=0; $i=$i-.01) {
        $val = $i;
        $val2 = $val * 100;
        echo "<option value='".$i."'";
        if($i == $rev_sel) echo "selected='selected'";
        echo ">".$val2."%</option>";
        }
```

As far as I can tell, this should end up with the 1% being selected when it pops up, or whatever $rev_sel is set to between 0 and 1.00.  It isn't the case.  Anybody know why?

Comment: Some programmers, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use floating point arithmetic." Now they have 1.999999999997 problems.

Comment: I guess I don't get the reference, I'm not a 30 year professional or anything, but it's printing out the select just fine and showing the values I want to use.

Comment: you cannot exact compare `==` of floating point data type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need to round like so:

```
<?php
$rev_sel = 0.01;
    for($i=1.00; $i>=0; $i=$i-.01) {
        $val = round($i, 2);
        $val2 = $val * 100;
        echo "<option value='".round($i,2)."'";
        if(round($i,2) == $rev_sel) echo "selected='selected'";
        echo ">".$val2."%</option>\n";
        }
```

Your code was outputting:

```
<option value='0.13'>13%</option>
<option value='0.12'>12%</option>
<option value='0.11'>11%</option>
<option value='0.099999999999999'>9.9999999999999%</option>
<option value='0.089999999999999'>8.9999999999999%</option>
<option value='0.079999999999999'>7.9999999999999%</option>
<option value='0.069999999999999'>6.9999999999999%</option>
```

0.00999999... etc is not equal to 0.01

Comment: Ugh I can't believe I forgot that, thanks for reminding me.  Floating point is silly.

Comment: Thanks :) Always check / test outputs!

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly compare floating point numbers. You're much better off comparing integers or strings, eg

```
<?php
$rev_sel = 1;
for ($i = 100; $i <= 0; $i--) :
$selected = $rev_sel == $i ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
?>
<option value="<?php printf('%.2f', $i / 100) ?>"<?php echo $selected ?>><?php echo $i ?>%</option> 
<?php endfor ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as like following to do exact comparison with floating value ...

```
$rev_sel = 0.01;
for($i=1.00; round($i,2) >= 0; $i = $i-.01) {
    $val = $i;
    $val2 = $val * 100;
    echo "<option value='".$i."'";
    if($i == $rev_sel) echo "selected='selected'";
    echo ">".$val2."%</option>";
    }
```